# Unable to update or install any software in Linux mint 17.3

Tags: installation, linux-mint, software-update

This is the error that throws up:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.domain.com/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.domain.com/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to packages.domain.com:http:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also have error in fontconfig and dpkg where this error throws up sometimes :

```
E: fontconfig: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

need help in solving this.

Thanks in advance for taking your time.

Comment: `packages.domain.com` seems to be a bad address (or is down).  try again later or find another repository mirror.  https://www.linuxmint.com/mirrors.php

Comment: The answers on this thread are more helpful and clearer than those on the linked answer. Also, this question has an accepted answer while the linked post does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links you are referencing are outdated (actually it was a bug in distribution). Disable it in "Software Sources" (or comment them out `/etc/apt/sources.list` ) and refresh updates.

Check also content of file:
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list`

It should contain at least:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa main upstream import 
deb http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa main
deb http://cosmos.cites.illinois.edu/pub/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://cosmos.cites.illinois.edu/pub/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
```

And comment out broken packages in this file.

To remove broken links - click on menu button in the left bottom corner and in the search field type: "Software sources", click on it and check all software sources for the presence of broken repositories.

Also make sure that packages:

```
libcurl3-gnutls
apt-transport-https
```

are installed.

Some repositories switched to `https` and if these packages are not installed you may get
`Failed to fetch` error again.

Regarding `fontconfig`, try to reinstall package:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge fontconfig-config
```

Comment: When I used sudo gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list it was a empty window and if I use synaptic package manager to find packages.domain.com it was not available. What should I do now to disable or comment out the bug ?

Comment: @Jayanthan You need to use `Software Manager`, not `synaptic`. I don't have access right now to LM to guide you exactly, but  you may try to go to the `Edit` menu and click on `Software sources` (should be somewhere there. I will take a look on it when I'm on LM and update my answer). Find affected sources and delete them.

Comment: @Jayanthan I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find how to check for broken repositories in software sources for Linux mint 17.3.

Comment: I still haven't been able to fix the issue.

Comment: Unable to view repositories in Software sources to comment them and also tried     sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list        It opens a empty file. Need help

Comment: @Jayanthan Take a look on updated answer, check content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` if  `/etc/apr/sources.list` is empty

Comment: In terminal it says permission denied and in Gedit I am not able to insert text to comment out broken packages and deb links you specified are only there and no other deb links are present. What do I have to do now?

Comment: @Jayanthan Run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` from terminal to edit that file